# sorting BIG excel data

Tags: sql, excel, sorting

Right so, I have been given a LOT of "consumer data" to sort, 3 excel files, each containing multiple worksheets, up to 7 worksheets, each up to 1M rows (max worksheet size in excel 2013 is just over 1 rows)

I need to pull out of these all people within a region, so have a list of post codes in this region (say 30 post code areas)

How can I achieve this most easily?

If the data was in SQL server, i'd just write a long SQL statement selecting all where postcode LIKE 'B75'% OR 'B74'% etc etc.
But in excel I can only run a "filer" on one worksheet at a time... (I think)

Is it going to be easiest to throw all the data into sql server, or have I overlooked a method?

Comment: You could achieve multiple filters by using helper columns where you add the appropriate formulas. However, given the data size, it will probably be easier for you to import the data into a SQL database or even MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

First solution is to let Excel do the task of sorting for you. You need to add filters to columns and select Sorting options.
Other solution is to Export Data to SQL Table(s). To do this, Open SQL Management Studio, Right Click on Database to which you want to export data to and Select "From Excel File". Do this for each Excel file you have. After importing all data in Database, sort Data using SQL Query.
Second Solution is reliable but first solution is faster. You need to decide which one you should select.

Comment: As i said the Filter only operates on one worksheet at once as far as i am aware, this would take FAR too long.

Comment: @DarkcatStudios Only solution is via SQL.